# How do you strip a graft using Mercurial and IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3

Tags: intellij-idea, mercurial, tortoisehg

I executed 31 grafts to a local branch and want to strip out 2 of the grafts. The problem is that the 2 grafts are somewhere in the middle, number 5 and 23 out of 31.

What do I execute to strip out these grafts? Also, is it possible to just strip out those 2 grafts specifically and not strip out subsequent grafts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the evolve extension. [Here are the evolve docs.](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/) It is a sharp knife, but a really user-friendly one. Main advice: *don't use it on changesets that you already pushed.* Let's repeat that:

### Assumption: you have not yet pushed any of the changesets you are about to remove, nor any of their descendants.

Check that assumption. Do (if `4` is the number of the earliest changeset  you want to prune):

```
hg log -r 'descendants(4)' --template '{rev}: {phase}\n{desc|firstline}\n'
```

This prints each changset, followed by its phase, and the first line of its commit message.

None of the phases should be `public`; all of them should be `draft`. (Or `secret`, but if you know about the `secret` phase then you clearly understand phases.)

Another assumption:

```
hg log --version
# Should be at least 3.4
```

### Installing hg-evolve

Instructions taken from [the wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EvolveExtension). First, clone the evolve repository, and checkout the tag corresponding to whichever version of mercurial you are running. There are tags for 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8. Ubuntu Xenial ships with Mercurial 3.7.

```
cd <dir>
hg clone https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/evolve/ --updaterev mercurial-3.7
```

Then edit your .hgrc:

```
[extensions]
evolve = <dir>/src/evolve-main/hgext/evolve.py
```

### Work in a clone, just to feel safe

For your peace of mind, do this in a clone. To make sure the cloned changesets remain in the `draft` phase, set your current repo to be non-publishing before pulling from it; otherwise the commits that get cloned will be marked as `public` on both server repo (the one getting talked to) and client (the one running the clone/pull/push command). The Evolve extension will only alter parts of the history tree that consist of draft changesets.

Mark the server repo, i.e. the one you're currently working on, as non-publishing, in its hgrc:

```
cd my-project
hg config --local
```

In the repo's hgrc:

```
[phases]
publish = False
```

Next, create the clone.

```
cd ..
hg clone my-project my-project2
cd my-project2
```

### Tell hg to prune the changesets and repair history

```
hg prune -r 23
```

This will make all changesets after 23 'unstable', because they are now based on a revision marked obsolete. You can see the new state of the history like so:

```
hg log --graph
```

The obsolete commit 23 will be marked with an `x`.

To fix the instability caused by modifying the history, run

```
hg evolve
```

Which will

- take the first unstable changeset (24),
- create a stable successor of 24 atop 23's successor -- because 23 was pruned, 24 will be moved atop 22. 24's successor will be e.g. 32.
- mark 24 obsolete.
- If there are merge conflicts because changeset 24 assumed context that was provided by 23, you will be prompted to resolve the conflicts.

Then, run `hg evolve` again; which will create a successor of the next unstable changeset in the right place (25 was atop 24; 24's successor is 32, so create 33 atop 32).

Run `hg evolve` again and again until all unstable changesets have been resolved. Once you feel confident that `hg evolve` does the right thing (it does), you can run `hg evolve --all` to move them one after another until there are no unstable changes left.

Now, the obsolete changesets will be automatically hidden: there are no non-obsolete changesets that depend on them anymore.

```
hg log --graph  # hides obsolete commits if they are irrelevant
hg log --graph --hidden  # also shows all obsolete commits
```

Once you're done with that, you can remove commit 4 in the same way:

```
hg prune -r 4
hg evolve --all
```

### If you want to see your history including obsolete changesets

```
hg log --graph --hidden
```

### Get your changes back to your main repo

In the `my-project2` repo, just push your changes back

```
hg push
```

This will push the new successors commits back to `my-project`. It will also push the obsolescence markers of the ones that were pruned or replaced by a successor.

### Clean up

- delete the `my-project2` repo (unless you want to keep it around)
- configure `my-project` as `publish = True` again (unless nobody but you pulls/clones from it)
- Decide whether to keep hg-evolve in your extensions. Core Mercurial understands obsolescence markers, so you're safe, there -- you can even use `hg log --hidden`. On the other hand, if `evolve` is not active and there are obsolescense markers in your repo, you'll sometimes (like when you run `hg log`) get a warning like `obsolete feature not enabled but 5 markers found!`